# I'm looking for a manga that has a game developer as the main character

Tags: story-identification, manga

There's this manga that I read a while ago, and it's about a guy who works in this company that develops action-based games. His co-workers are all very rude to him, except for this lady who is super friendly to him (in a professional way). I think he's the main developer or he has a major role in the game they are making. The company is putting everything in this game and they are putting a lot of pressure on him.

Somehow, the game becomes real (I don't remember how) and monsters show up in the office they all work in. He gets them all to safety through his knowledge of what happens in the game. He then finds a room with an easter egg in it that he made. (It's a skeleton version of him sitting at a desk.) That's all I remember for the beginning; I do remember that later on they run into some guy who used to work for the company and he helps them out.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[The King of Gaming Bugs!](https://anilist.co/manga/132791/Wo-Kao-BUG-Shang-Wangzhe/)*

> Computer game programmer, Xander Song spends his days suffering under his abusive boss and cruel coworkers. Tasked with debugging a new video game called “New Realm,” Xander instead transforms the bugs into easter eggs for only the worthiest of players to uncover. One fateful day, reality rewrites itself and merges with “New Realm.” Thrust into a whole new world, Xander must find his way among desperate players while beating dangerous bosses. Will Xander’s knowledge of the game be enough to survive? Or will it be GAME OVER before he knows it?

The synopsis covers the easter eggs and sudden appearance of a new environment. As mentioned in the question, it's filled with hostile monsters that try to kill the employees.

The main character isn't the lead programmer; he's low ranked and is just tasked with fixing bugs before the game is released. He converts them into easter eggs and uses his knowledge of them in the new world.

Including the skeleton:

[image: Overworked Programmer]